# Next.js 301: How to redirect from source only if a query param is missing?

Tags: javascript, redirect, next.js, next.js13

1. I have a source URL like https://example.com/category/results/refine?dealers=123&inv=true
2. I want to implement an SSR permanent 301 redirect to destination URL like https://example.com/ if the source URL does NOT contains the inv key.

Is it possible ?

```js
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/category/results/refine",
        has: [
          {
            type: "query",
            key: "dealers",
          },
          {
            type: "query",
            key: "inv",
            // value: "true", // redirect only if missing?
          },
        ],
        destination: "/",
        permanent: true,
        statusCode: 301,
      },
}
```